# Datetimepicker in two steps

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

In the bootstrap datetimepicker when I select the day, then I can choose the hour and then the minutes.

Is there any way that I can choose the day and then the hour with all minutes directly, in two steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<br/>
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/tu5n0387/)

Comment: Well but I can do this without clicking the clock button? only when I click the day.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain. I didn't get you

Comment: Could you do this without having to press the clock button?
 
I want you to press the date directly to select the hours.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: So you don't want to select the time. It should be automatic ?

Comment: Not but now the calendar has a button to go to "hour step", 
I need to go to the step of selecting the time, when I select the day, not when I click the clock button.